# Installing R package on linux built on windows

Tags: r

I have a package on windows that builds successfully and works on a windows machine and I would like to make it available on a linux machine

Here are the steps I took in windows

1. I went to build >> Build Binary package and this created a zip file packageA.zip
2. Then I used tar to make a tar file from the zip file

   `tar("packageA.tar.gz" , "C://users/me/packageA.zip)`
3. Then I try to install the package on the linux machine

   `install.packages("packageA.tar.gz")`

but, I get this error

> installation of package 'packageA.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status.

Any idea how to install this on linux?

Comment: Build a source package and install that on the other machine, though ideally you would use local source code control via `git` or something and then have that repo on both system and then just do the build on the other system.

Comment: Build a source package.  Install the source package on the other machine.  Ignore or all other complication -- revision control repo etc can come after you have it working first.